# Can you upload a file from a Cloudpage into a Marketing Cloud FTP

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage, fileupload

I'm wondering if it's possible to use a form upload on a Cloudpage to upload a file into our Marketing Cloud FTP?

Thanks in advance!

-Nikki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are wanting to have a CloudPage form where a customer can fill in their details and then attach a file - which you then want the file to upload to the FTP server ?

Ampscript and SSJS do not support much in terms of file manipulation on FTP; and it wouldn't be an approach I would suggest either, as the FTP is your 'back door' for getting data into marketing cloud, so you really don't want to keep it open to web users. Also, the FTP server would automatically purge data files after a time.

One possibility you could try is to [base64 encode](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Base64Encode.htm) the file and store the base64 encoded file in a Text field of a data extension. It's not something I've ever tried to do with a cloud page, but might it might lead you to a solution.

Another avenue to investigate is whether you can upload the file to the Content Library / Portfolio of Content Builder. Again, it's not ideal as you will pollute your asset library and also the cost of storage might be high.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! That's exactly what we were thinking of building. I thought it was a bit of a stretch

Answer (score 2):

You can do this but not directly. You would have to run a data extract on the data extension the form goes to and transfer it into the ftp. You can put these two into an automation in automation studio and run this job in 1 hour batches

Comment: hhmmm - I'm not sure this is correct. Running a data extract on the data extension is simply going to get you the data from the data extension. Reading the question, I believe it's asked how to upload a file from a form, and store this in the FTP server e.g. a customer attaching a word document.